# Disable dates in MonthView Control In Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Monthview Control and am trying to deactivate dates in it. Eg: I have two cells where the dates are being entered from monthview, which represents the start date and the end date. The allowed period is 20 days from the start date, dates after that should be grayed out in the Monthview Control for end date.